# Code works when running node console but not when invoking node <app_name.js>

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using:

```
npm install babyparse --save
```

when invoking

```
node
```

in Terminal (OS X Yosemite), I run the following commands and see output:

```
> var Baby = require('babyparse');
undefined
> var fs_test_data = Baby.parseFiles('fs_test.csv');
undefined
> var rows = fs_test_data.data;
undefined
>     rows.forEach(function(element, index, array){
...         console.log(element);
...         console.log(index);
...     });
[ '3000', '    1000', '    2000', '    30', '    0', '    1', '' ]
0
[ '3000', '    1000', '    2000', '    40', '    0', '    5', '' ]
1
undefined
>
```

That's great! it works!

But....

```
//test_babyparse.js
var Baby = require('babyparse');
var fs_test_data = Baby.parseFiles('fs_test.csv');
var rows = fs_test_data.data;
rows.forEach(function(element, index, array){
    console.log(element);
    console.log(index);
});
```

and running

```
node test_babyparse.js
```

Ends up showing nothing. Why? Does this have to do with the IO and Event Loop?

Thanks,

Zakiir

---

Edit: I'm using the babyparse.js file found on github, NOT the .js file found on npm which does not have the parseFiles function.

Comment: could be an error that happened, babyparse provides an error variable you can check by doing console.log(fs_test_data.error)

Comment: yep, looks as though there's a `ReferenceError: fs is not defined`. Programming bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phew!

so yes, I looked through the source of the babyparse.js file and noticed 'fs' was not defined.

I wrote

```
fs = require('fs');
```

in my test_babyparse.js, which I believe sets 'fs' in the global scope.

It worked!

---

Edit: Apparently it's not good practice to add things to global scope like that, so I added

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

in the babyparse.js file.